# How to display a list of bill?

Tags: java, formatting, billing

I have declared "price" and "category", now I wish to display like this:

```
productname     price       id      amount
water           25          3       3(bottles)
```

(a list at the end of output that shows the bill)

How to do that?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
do {
    String Enterproducts=in.next();
    if(Enterproducts.equals("Stop")){
        break;
    }
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<category.length; i++){
        if(Enterproducts.equals(category[i])){
            System.out.print(" "+category[i]+" "+price[i]+" "+n);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
} while(in.hasNext());
```

Comment: Your code is working but the output isn't aligned, right? Is this the problem?

Comment: yes how to print everything together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
do {
    String Enterproducts=in.next();
    if(Enterproducts.equals("Stop")){
        break;
    }
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0; i<category.length; i++){
        if(Enterproducts.equals(category[i])){
            System.out.print(String.format("%-20s %s",category[i], price[i], n));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
} while(in.hasNext());
```

With `%-20s` you are specifing a space lenght.

As an alternative, you can do it as you did it before, but using tabs instead spaces (tabs = `\t`).